Best practices for pixel art background sizes?
I'm looking to start making pixel art for my 2d side-scrolling game prototype. I'm looking for advice on how large to make my pixel art backgrounds. I watched this video before I began to get an idea of common sprite sizes.  I decided to take the advice and use 32x32 character sprites. Now I'm wanting to know how large to make the background images.
I tried making an image of the player's house location to test it out. I tried making it 100x100 at first, then when that was a bit small, increased the canvas size to 150x150, then 200x200. When I imported the resized versions, I don't think I noticed much change in Unity, aside from them looking a bit blurry now. I'm not sure if this was from me resizing the images, rather than redrawing them.

This depends on what screen resolutions you want to support, how big you want your character to be relative to the screen, and of course your art style / visual target. There's no simple correct answer or starting guideline to go from, just a number of considerations you'll need to weigh as the art director for your game. See past Q&A like What sprite size should I use for a 2D game?
